# How to load COM object in smart device project?

Tags: c#, com, windows-mobile, compact-framework, activex

I want to create a .NET CF application for Windows Mobile 5. In this application, I want to load a COM object based on the ProgID (or CLSID).

1. How do I load this COM object in such a way that I can access its methods as if it were just another .NET object?
2. In addition: how can I configure the projects / solutions in Visual Studio in such a way, that when I debug the application, I am sure that the COM object that is loaded is the one that is installed on the device, not one that may be accessible through the debugger?

I have tried adding the .ocx file as a Reference, but I get an error, and I am not sure about 'question 2'. I have also tried loading the COM object using

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("my.prog.id")
MyObject myObject = (MyObject)Activator.CreateInstance(type)
```

...but this results in an InvalidCastException on the second line.

---

**EDIT:** For the record: I am working on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine, not sure if this complicates things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a runtime callable wrapper (RCW).  See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446523.aspx) for the basics.  For more complex things like ActiveX controls, see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446515.aspx).

Comment: I have created the RCW by adding a reference to the .tlb file. It also seems that I am able to instantiate an object. However, calling a method on that object results in a COMException (0x8000ffff). I know for a fact that the COM object itself works just fine when called from another application, however, that is a native application of which I do not have the source code.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, as it is probably the most direct answer to my question. The COMException that I encounter is probably due to the fact that I do not use the COM component correctly (incorrect order of function calls, etc.) which causes it to generate an error.